# How to halt asp UpdateProgress on error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, updateprogress

I have an update progress with a spinner in it. On click of a search button, the spinner shows, and when it gets it's response the spinner goes away. This is all automated by the listview and asp update progress controls.

However, I have found that if an error occurs on the server side during this async postback, or the postback takes too longer, than the spinner will just keep spinning indefinitely.

Is there a way to recognize if an error has happened or if a request has timed out and then unload the updateprogress? I was on the trail of maybe recognizing an error through the scriptmanager, but got lost.

Comment: Are the errors caught in a try/catch?

Comment: Some of them would be. At the moment I am just trying to plan for the unexpected error, one that I wouldn't know exists. What I did was just put a divide by zero exception in the code to see how the sinner reacted and it just keeps spinning forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the beginRequest and endRequest events of the PageRequestManager class if you haven't already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I've used those progress spinners before but haven't noticed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

See this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1266920.aspx  It essentially says you must manipulate the element manually by attaching to Sys.Application.beginRequest and endRequest.